# "@Where" and "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" not working at the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have JPA entity(Product Entity) which use the `@Where` annotation per bellow , and at the same time , I am using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` as well.  ( `Product` is a Parent Entity and `Storage` is a Child Entity)

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productid")
    @Immutable
    @Where(clause = "isprimary='true'")
    private List<Storage> storageList;
```

Problem happens when I want to delete the `Product` (Parent) Entity. Since "`Product`" Entity has a relation to "Storage" Entity and I am using "Where" annotation with the criteria "isprimary=true" , It would not delete the "`Storage`" Entity which has a isrimary=false .
Any suggestion that how can I resolve the issue .
My request is , how may I delete all Storage(Child) Entity ( whether has isprimary is true or false) and at the same time , I can use the @Where anotation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a second list with the other entries:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productid")
@Immutable
@Where(clause = "isprimary='true'")
private List<Storage> storageList;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productid")
@Immutable
@Where(clause = "isprimary='false'")
private List<Storage> storageListNotPrimary;
```